# Parse entire soap response in android with ksoap2-android

Tags: android, soap, response, ksoap2

I'm calling a web service with my android app, and there are no errors, but I'm stuck on next point:

Here is my response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
       <ns4:conResponse returnStatus="SRV_STATUS_SUCCESS" xmlns:ns5="https://myserver.fr/Server/GameOps/" xmlns:ns4="https://myserver.fr/Server/MainOps/" xmlns:ns3="https://myserver.fr/Server/CoreServices/" xmlns:ns2="https://myserver.fr/Server/Models/"/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this code

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
int count = result.getPropertyCount();
int count2 = result.getAttributeCount();
```

return count = 0 and count2 = 0

I need to get returnStatus attribute, how can I do that?

**Edit 1**
I'm preparing my request like this:

```
String NAMESPACE = "https://myserver.fr/Server/MainOps/";
String METHODNAME = "conRequest";
String URL = "myserver.com/myproject/MainOpsSOAP";
String SOAPACTION = NAMESPACE + "connect";

SoapObject main = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME);
main.addProperty("id", "id1");
main.addProperty("name", "name1");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(main);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAPACTION, envelope);

return envelope;
```

**Edit 2**
I tried to modify my complexType and here what I noticed

When my response definition look like this :

```
<xsd:complexType name="WSResponse">
    <xsd:attribute name="returnStatus" type="coreservices:ReturnStatusEnum" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

my envelope.bodyIn doesn't contain any Attributes or Properties,

but when I modify this definition by this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="WSResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="returnStatus" type="coreservices:ReturnStatusEnum" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

my envelope.bodyIn contains "returnStatus" **property**

Answer (score 0):

When you get envelope you must do this

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject resultCollection = result.getProperty("getMethodCollectionResult");
int count = resultCollection.getPropertyCount();
int count2 = resultCollection.getAttributeCount();
```

Comment: But in my case, my "result" has not properties, so SoapObject resultCollection = result.getProperty("getMethodCollectionResult"); will return nothing.

Comment: It's strange that you don't have property... Can you let the wsdl url's ?

Comment: Have you try this `SoapObject resultCollection = result.getProperty("connectPlayerResponse");` or with your method you want ?

Comment: yes, I tried, but it throws an exception with the message "illegal connectPlayerResponse". Look to my second edit, there's some update